# Get Collection With HasOne Relationship

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

In my User model in Laravel 5.2 I have a relationship setup with their status to the company.

```
public function companyStatus()
{
    return $this->hasOne('CompanyUser')->select('status');
}
```

The CompanyUser table has a company_id, user_id, and status field

Then in my controller I do the following:

```
$company   = Company::find($company_id);
$users     = CompanyUser::where('company_id', $company_id)->pluck('user_id')->toArray();
$user_data = User::with('companyStatus')->find($users);
```

but when I dump the user_data array it has all of the users related to the company, but just shows **null** for their status relationship

```
{
   "id":2,
   "name":"Moderator",
   "email":"mod@company.com",
   "created_at":"2016-09-08 15:26:20",
   "updated_at":"2016-09-08 15:26:25",
   "company_status":null
 }
```

If I however return just the User collection to the view, and iterate over each user and run

```
$user->companyStatus->status
```

the value displays, but I am trying to include this within the collection for a JSON API to consume.

**UPDATE**

I tried adding the foreign key to the select call on my relationship method:

```
public function companyStatus()
{
    return $this->hasOne('CompanyUser')->select('status', 'user_id');
}
```

and it now returns the following:

```
{
   "id":2,
   "name":"Moderator",
   "email":"mod@company.com",
   "created_at":"2016-09-08 15:26:20",
   "updated_at":"2016-09-08 15:26:25",
   "company_status": {"status":"1","user_id":"2"}
 }
```

Not sure if this is the best/correct method or not though.

Comment: Without selecting the foreign key, it can't determine the related data/records on other table so it's required and you are on the right track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I figured it out.

I tried adding the foreign key to the select call on my relationship method:

```
public function companyStatus()
{
    return $this->hasOne('CompanyUser')->select('status', 'user_id');
}
```

Then that returns:

```
{
   "id":2,
   "name":"Moderator",
   "email":"mod@company.com",
   "created_at":"2016-09-08 15:26:20",
   "updated_at":"2016-09-08 15:26:25",
   "company_status": {"status":"1","user_id":"2"}
}
```

Without the foreign key Laravel obviously can't determine the related data on the other table.